# Angular - Use row class on outside div with child custom components

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have a customized component with bootstrap columns as input parameters that works like this:

```html
<div *ngIf="isColumn" [ngClass]="'col-md-' + labelColumns">
    <label>
        {{label}}
        <i *ngIf="isRequired" class="required-asterisk">*</i>:
    </label>
</div>

<div *ngIf="isColumn" [ngClass]="'col-md-' + inputColumns">
    <input [attr.maxlength]="maxLength" [(ngModel)]="value" [eds-required]="isRequired" />
</div>
```

I want to control the row class from outside this template so i can create multiple inline components like this one. So i did this:

```html
<div class="row no-gutters">
    <quick-text-input isColumn="true" isRequired="true" label="TESTE"></quick-text-input>
</div>
```

However, the text input components are appearing above each other, as if the template didn't recognize the outside div's row class.

Is there a way for bootstrap div rows to align custom templates with columns?

Edit: labelColumns and inputColumns are two input variables with default values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bootstrap 3, the CSS used for the `row` class was `display: table`. The code you have written would work if used with Bootstrap 3 (along with the right Bootstrap 3 class names). Bootstrap 4, on the other hand, is built with [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox), so the `row` class now uses `display: flex` instead. When `display: flex;` is used, it only applies to its direct children. In your code, the direct children of the container that uses `row` contain `quick-text-input` and the first element within `quick-text-input` contains the `col-md-` classes, so your grid will break since the contents of `quick-text-input` are not direct children of the `row` container.

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox#The_flex_container):

> To create a flex container, we set the value of the area's container's `display` property to `flex` or `inline-flex`. As soon as we do this the direct children of that container become `flex` items.

What you need is basically a nested flexbox where the inner flexbox would be `quick-text-input` and the outer one would be the `div` in your parent component which encapsulates the `quick-text-input` elements.

**quick-text-input.component.html**

```html
<div class="row">
    <div *ngIf="isColumn" class="col-4">
        <label>
            {{label}}<i *ngIf="isRequired" class="required-asterisk">*</i> :
        </label>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="isColumn" class="col-8">
        <input class="form-control" [attr.maxlength]="maxLength" [(ngModel)]="value" />
    </div>
</div>
```

You don't seem to be passing `labelColumns` and `inputColumns` as `@Input` so I have just changed them to `col-md-4` and `col-md-8` respectively. You can used `labelColumns` and `inputColumns` if you need them.

Now, in the parent component, depending on how many elements we need in a row, we need to set the `col-` class in our `quick-text-input` element.

```html
<div class="row">
    <span class="mb-2 mx-3">Single element in row</span>
    <quick-text-input class="col-12" isColumn="true" isRequired="true" label="TESTE"></quick-text-input>

    <span class="w-100 mb-2 mx-3">Two elements in a row</span>
    <quick-text-input class="col-6" isColumn="true" isRequired="true" label="TESTE"></quick-text-input>
    <quick-text-input class="col-6" isColumn="true" isRequired="true" label="TESTE"></quick-text-input>
</div>
```

Here is an example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-nested-grid). This is how the [output](https://angular-bootstrap-nested-grid.stackblitz.io/) will look.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for.Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could move the `row` class of bootstrap directly to the component tag and also if you're using bootstrap 4, you need to use `col-3` instead of `col-md-3`, below is a working example, please let me know if this fixes your issue!

```
// app.component.html
<app-test class="row no-gutters" isColumn="true" isRequired="true" label="TESTE"></app-test>

// test.component.html
<div *ngIf="isColumn" class="col-{{ labelColumns }}">
    <label>{{label}}<i *ngIf="isRequired" class="required-asterisk">*</i>:</label>
</div>

<div *ngIf="isColumn" class="col-{{ inputColumns }}">
    <input [attr.maxlength]="maxLength" [(ngModel)]="value" />
</div>
```

<kbd>**StackBlitz**</kbd>

Comment: Hello! The problem with this approach is that i can only have a test.component.html per row, but i want multiple test components in a row assigned to a div outside them.

Answer (score 0):

you are right , this sholud work like in this example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4qn1de

Even if your "labelColumns" is undefined, the input-field are aligned in a row.

**But**, if i'm removing the boostrap-import from style.css, then the input-fields are align amonng themselves.

Comment: I cannot remove Bootstrap as the whole application depends on it